# VBA Excel can't append string to existing value

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on automatization, whose goal is copying the existing row to the newly inserted line and changing the job name.
All of the things have been completed successfully except for the string, which can't be appended.

My formula looks like this:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("CC3:CC300")) Is Nothing Then
 End If

 If ActiveCell.Value = "Re-design " Then

 RowToCopy = ActiveCell.Row
 insertRow = ActiveCell.Row + 1

 Rows(RowToCopy).Copy
 Rows(insertRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown

 Dim x As String, y As String, z As String, v As String

 x = "AP" & insertRow & ":" & "DW" & insertRow

 Range(x).ClearContents

 y = "A" & RowToCopy & ":" & "DW" & RowToCopy

 Range(y).Interior.ColorIndex = 15

 z = "A" & insertRow
 v = "A" & RowToCopy.Value

 Range(z).Value = v & "/2"

 End If

 End Sub
```

but at the line:

```
 Range(z).Value = v & "/2"
```

I get an error: Object required.

Is there any way of appending value to the existing value of the cell?

[image]

UPDATE:

I did also:
Range(z).Value = v.Value & "/2"

But now says: Invalid qualifier

Comment: `v = "A" & RowToCopy.Value`: this is invalid. `RowToCopy` is a row number. It doesn't have a `.Value`.

Comment: Yes, but if i remove the .value then the cell like A3 is copied as a string instead

Comment: Of course. If you want to refer to the cell A3 and `v` = `"A3"`, then use `Me.Range(v)`.

Comment: `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("CC3:CC300")) Is Nothing Then
 End If` ... this does absolutely nothing.

Comment: `Shift:=xlShiftDown` the proper enumeration

Comment: Yes but this cell will change. If I use the dropdown from the row 12th for example what cell would be then?

Comment: `v.Value & "/2"`: `v` doesn't have a `.Value` either.

Answer (score 0):

I found the smart answer:

This link shows how to do it:

https://forum.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/75631-append-text-to-existing-cell-text/

The code must be:

```
    Range(z).Value = Range(v).Value & "/2"
```